# Database query always returns TRUE

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to find if row exists in database.  This code always returns TRUE. I want to add the row if it doesn't exist.
See test code below.

```
 // CHECK IF RECORD EXISTS
  if (array_key_exists('test', $_GET)) {
    if(coupleRowExists($_GET['male'], $_GET['female'])) {
      echo 'EXISTS';
    } else {
      echo 'Does NOT exist';
    }
  }

  // CHECK DB FOR THIS COUPLE
  function coupleRowExists($male, $female) {
    global $db;
    $sp_couple_exists = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `couples` 
                         WHERE male = ? AND female = ? )";
    return ($db->prepare($sp_couple_exists)->execute([$male, $female]));
  }
```

Comment: You are executing the SQL Query but not checking the result before return. After execute, `fetchAll` and then finally use `if else` to see if `rowCount` is `>= 1`. If yes, `return true` and if now `return false`.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi `rowCount` doesnt work for selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with user3783243 in that rowCount does not always work with SELECT (see PHP Manual->PDOStatement::rowCount().  They recommend use of COUNT as follows:

```
function coupleRowExists($m, $f) {
    global $db;
    $sp = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `couples` WHERE male = ? AND female = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sp);
    $stmt->execute([$m, $f]);
    $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    return $count;
  }
```

This has proven reliable.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
return ($db->prepare($sp_couple_exists)->execute([$male, $female]));
```

Will return true when the database query is executed successfully, not necessarily if there is a result or not.  Which, if you wrote the query properly, will be all the time.

If you want to find out if it actually returned a row, then you'll want to check for an actual returned row.

I would modify this a bit so it returns that and is a bit cleaner:

```
function coupleRowExists($male, $female) {
  global $db;
  $sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM couples WHERE male = ? AND female = ?)";
  $db->prepare ($sql);
  $db->execute ([$male, $female]);

  if ($db->rowCount()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

execute() will return only true or false. Here's a link for a reference. 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Here's a modified function for the same.

```
function coupleRowExists($male, $female) {
  global $db;
  $sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM couples WHERE male = ? AND female = ?)";
  $db->prepare ($sql);
  $result = $db->execute ([$male, $female]);

  if ($result && $db->rowCount() > 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```